# Reactjs- How do I pass data or a variable from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I am trying to access CmpnyCode variable from companymstlist in editcompany.js
After accessing this I can use that CmpnyCode to get data with that code into form for editting.
Initially I was working with Hooks but there seems to be an issue with my react-router-dom hence I want to pass the variable from the table component to the edit form component.

**This is my editcompany.js:**

```
//import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState /*useEffect*/ } from "react";
//import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const initialValues = {
  CompanyCode: "",
  CompanyName: "",
  Address1: "",
  Address2: "",
  PoBox: "",
  City: "",
  Province: "",
  Country: "",
  Phone: "",
  Fax: "",
  Email: "",
  RegistrationNo: "",
  VatNo: "",
  PinNo: "",
  BranchNo: "",
  BranchHq: "",
  StartDate: "",
  EndDate: "",
  Current: "",
  RunDate: "",
  DateCreated: "",
  UserID: "",
  LocationID: "",
};

const CompanyMaster_Edit = () => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(initialValues);
  const {
    CompanyCode,
    CompanyName,
    Address1,
    Address2,
    PoBox,
    City,
    Province,
    Country,
    Phone,
    Fax,
    Email,
    RegistrationNo,
    VatNo,
    PinNo,
    BranchNo,
    BranchHq,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    Current,
    RunDate,
    DateCreated,
    UserID,
    LocationID,
  } = company;

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   loadData();
  // });

  // const loadData = () => {
  //   const response = axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/getcomcode/${CmpnyCode}`);
  //   setCompany(response.data);
  // };

  const onValueChange = (e) => {
    setCompany({ ...company, [e.target.CompanyCode]: e.target.value });
  };

  // const editData = () => {
  //   axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/upcompanymst/${CmpnyCode}`);
  //   history.push("/companymst");
  // };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form>
            <h3> Edit Company Master</h3>
            <div className="form-class8">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Company Code</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="CompanyCode"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="CompanyCode"
                  value={CompanyCode}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Company Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="CompanyName"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="CompanyName"
                  value={CompanyName}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Address1</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Address1"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Address1"
                  value={Address1}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Address2</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Address2"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Address2"
                  value={Address2}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>PO Box</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="PO Box"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="PoBox"
                  value={PoBox}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="City"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="City"
                  value={City}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Province</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Province"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Province"
                  value={Province}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Country</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Country"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Country"
                  value={Country}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-class8">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Phone"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Phone"
                  value={Phone}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Fax</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Fax"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Fax"
                  value={Fax}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Email"
                  value={Email}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Registration No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="RegistrationNo"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="RegistrationNo"
                  value={RegistrationNo}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>VAT No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="VAT No"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="VatNo"
                  value={VatNo}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Pin No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Pin No"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="PinNo"
                  value={PinNo}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Branch No</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Branch No"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="BranchNo"
                  value={BranchNo}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Branch Hq</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Branch Hq"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="BranchHq"
                  value={BranchHq}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-class8">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Start Date</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Start Date"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="StartDate"
                  value={StartDate}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="End Date"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="EndDate"
                  value={EndDate}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Current</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Current"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="Current"
                  value={Current}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Run Date</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Run Date"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="RunDate"
                  value={RunDate}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Date Created</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Date Created"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="DateCreated"
                  value={DateCreated}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>User ID</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="User ID"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="UserID"
                  value={UserID}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Location ID</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="Location ID"
                  onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
                  name="LocationID"
                  value={LocationID}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <button
              className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              /*onClick={() => editData()}*/
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CompanyMaster_Edit;
```

**This is my companymstlist.js:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Container, Row, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const AllCompanies = () => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/companymst").then((response) => {
      setCompanies(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const deleteRecord = (CmpnyCode) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/deletecompanymst/${CmpnyCode}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <Container className="container">
            <Row className="row">
              <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>CompanyCode</th>
                    <th>CompanyName</th>
                    <th>Address1</th>
                    <th>Address2</th>
                    <th>PoBox</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Province</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>RegistrationNo</th>
                    <th>VatNo</th>
                    <th>PinNo</th>
                    <th>BranchNo</th>
                    <th>BranchHq</th>
                    <th>StartDate</th>
                    <th>EndDate</th>
                    <th>Current</th>
                    <th>RunDate</th>
                    <th>DateCreated</th>
                    <th>UserID</th>
                    <th>LocationID</th>
                    <th colSpan="2">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {companies.map((val) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{val.CmpnyCode}</td>
                        <td>{val.CmpnyName}</td>
                        <td>{val.Address1}</td>
                        <td>{val.Address2}</td>
                        <td>{val.PoBox}</td>
                        <td>{val.City}</td>
                        <td>{val.Province}</td>
                        <td>{val.Country}</td>
                        <td>{val.Phone}</td>
                        <td>{val.Fax}</td>
                        <td>{val.Email}</td>
                        <td>{val.RegistrationNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.VatNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.PinNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.BranchNo}</td>
                        <td>{val.BranchHq}</td>
                        <td>{val.StartDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.EndDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.Current.data[0]}</td>
                        <td>{val.RunDate}</td>
                        <td>{val.DateCreated}</td>
                        <td>{val.UserID}</td>
                        <td>{val.LocationID}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Link to={`/upcompanymaster/${val.CmpnyCode}`}>
                            <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Button
                            variant="danger"
                            onClick={() => {
                              deleteRecord(val.CmpnyCode);
                            }}
                          >
                            Delete
                          </Button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCompanies;
```

Please I would appreciate an answer before any minus points. I have been stuck at this for a week now and am unable to move on. Please help

Comment: 1. you can use redux and connect the store to you form and get the data in the form and vice versa, 2. you make an api call and get the data in the form again then save it by api, so when you go back to display component it would fetch the new data 3. move your state to parent component where both form and display components are child components then you can pass the data and onChange method as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Redux** or **NgRx** state managers which help in maintaining a global/sub app states. Both the components can be directly connect to the store and access the state data through props, and update using actions/reducers.

You can check out some tutorial videos on youtube they'll give you a detailed walkthrough.